# How to extract only date from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to extract only date from below string and extract year alone from this date.

String:

```
'I was born on 1st Jan 1994'
```

Do we have any function to extract dates from strings other than left or right functions ?

```sql
SELECT RIGHT('I was born on 1st Jan 1994', 12)
```

Result: '1st Jan 1994'

But I need result in date format.

Comment: None of the styles for `CONVERT` support dates where the day has a suffix (`st`, `th`, etc). Honestly, you should be fixing your application layer so that it doesn't pass the value as a sentence like this in the first place and puts the date of birth in a `date` column.

Comment: There's no general solution to this problem, it depends on the input string format. How do we know the incoming string value can't be "Hi I have a cat named mittens which I bought in 2003, and then I went and saw a movie on Jan 21 2009, which wasn't very good, and I was born on the 1st Jan 1994, and in 2023 I am going to start a SQL course"?

Comment: _Do we have any function to extract ..._ Yes there is an entire section in the documentation on the various string functions provided in your version of sql server. But as already suggested, your problem may be vastly more complicated depending on the values that might be found in your column / string. Will every string follow your example?

Comment: And this goal "extract year alone" is not consistent with "I need result in date format".

Comment: Slight detour....are you actually using 2012? It's end of life is less than a week away. Time to consider upgrading.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score -4):

Please check my code and resultset for your request: I mostly used another string functions other than left() and right(): I hope It solves your problem.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @extract VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @onlydate VARCHAR(20)
SET @string = 'I was born on 1st Jan 1994'
SET @extract = SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('1st', @string), len(@string))
SET @onlydate = REPLACE(@extract, 'st', '')
SELECT @string as full_text, @extract as extracted_text, @onlydate as only_datetext,CONVERT(date,@onlydate,102) as string_to_date;
```

Result_Set
[image: query result_string_to_date]

Comment: This only works if the string contains "1st". It isn't even close to all the possibilities needed for something like this.

Comment: @Sean Lange what other possibilities ? I think the purpose here is to focus on the problem at hand, not on all possibilities.

Comment: OK. I suppose if you want to only focus on the exact string they posted this works, but it is entirely short sighted. For example, you code fails to work correctly if we change the value to "I was born on 2nd Jan 1994".  And the actual question asked is "Do we have any function to extract dates from strings other than left or right functions ?". Your code does not handle that.

Comment: @Sean substring(), char index(), replace() are not considered a function in your eyes?  For me, they are string functions. Am I wrong? You understand the question correctly, but your answer conflicts.

Comment: That was what the OP asked. Again if you really think you solution will find dates you might need to look closer. It finds the exact string in the example the OP posted and nothing else. They want to extract dates embedded in strings not this exact one.

Comment: Yes, That's what the OP asked. Case closed for me. Good luck in your search for the perfect solution.

Comment: There isn't even a reasonably decent solution. The OP's data is a trainwreck and they are essentially asking for the impossible.

Comment: The question was only asked 3 hours ago. Is it not too early to say that the one who asked the question is asking for the impossible ? To be honest, I expected a more positive and encouraging answer from you.

Comment: If you think a solution that works for this exact string and no other is sufficent, then surely the simplest, perfectly acceptable answer would be `select cast('19940101' as date)`. No?

Comment: @allmhuran No! you don't even need the cast function. write the date directly: '1994-01-01' . just spend your time on the question asked.

Comment: @OzanSen That would return a `varchar`, not a `date`.

Comment: @allmhuran yes, you are absolutely right! :)